# Error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'

Tags: angular

I have just updated to angular 9! and suddenly I got this exception:
`Error occurs in the template of *, error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'`

Here is the template:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onLogin(frm.value)" #frm="ngForm" style="margin:0 auto;"> //All of these was working fine before the update
```

I also imported `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule`, `CommonModule` in `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
HttpClientModule,
FormsModule, 
ReactiveFormsModule,
CommonModule,
```

Note, I am using Visual Studio angular template.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to add the `ngForm` directive to the form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onLogin(frm.value)" ngForm #frm style="margin:0 auto;">
```

Comment: Thanks, I did with no change, the VS Code is underlining in red `"ngForm"` in `#frm="ngForm"`. should it be `div` tag instead of `form` in that case?

Comment: is your login component declared in a module where the FormsModule is imported?

Comment: Yes, the component is in the same module, it was just `ngForm #frm` instead of  `#frm="ngForm"`, thank you for help.

Comment: It changed between angular 8 and 10

Answer (score -1):

**A bit of knowledge :**

**the libraries we are going to use in our web app should be imported and should be
added imported array of the parent module .**

In abv eg .
'Form module' should be imported in app.module.ts file and should be added to the 'imports:[]' array of app.module.ts to make it available for its child components.

this should be done cause once you imported the library in parent(eg. m_name.module.ts )
it'll allow that library to its child components(eg. C_name.component.ts)

this is how the **Mr. Angular work .**
:D:D